# How to create a table with columns' names and values from other tables

Tags: sql-server, join, select

I have a project for a Shoes-company that needs to join 3 tables. I could do it with DataTable in C# winform but just wonder if I can combine directly in SQL.

Table1 names MoldQty that I will use 3 columns

```
Model | Size |MoldQuantity
--------------------------
AAA   |6.5   | 1    
AAA   |7     | 2    
AAA   |7.5   | 1    
AAA   |8     | 2    
AAA   |8.5   | 1    
AAA   |9     | 2    
AAA   |9.5   | 1
```

Table 2 names Order that has many other columns

```
Order Num   | Model | 
---------------------
20200101xx  | AAA   |    
20200101xy  | AAA   |    
20200101yy  | BBB   |
```

Table 3 names OrderDetail

```
Order Num   | Size |Quantity
----------------------------
20200101xx  | 6.5  |100    
20200101xx  | 7.5  |100    
20200101xx  | 8.5  |200    
20200101xy  | 7    |100    
20200101xy  | 8    |100    
20200101xy  | 9    |200
```

Now I want to make a Table all Orders for Model AAA with Some columns that Column's name comes from MoldQty.Size and Value come from OrderDetail.Quantity

```
Order Num   | 6.5  | 7    | 7.5  | 8    | 8.5  | 9    | 9.5  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
20200101xx  | 100  | Null | 100  | Null | 200  | Null | Null |    
20200101xy  | Null | 100  | Null | 100  | Null | 100  | Null |
```

Do anyone have any idea? Thank you so much.

Comment: You could do this in tsql with the PIVOT operator.  I would not do it in SQL , though.  I guess you want the columns to be dynamic (the value of your size can change).  You could do this with dynamic SQL.  But I think it's more logic to do this in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

A reference to the MoldQty table is only necessary if the query is made dynamic.  Here are sample tables, data, and query.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Order;
GO
CREATE TABLE #Order
(OrderNum CHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
 Model    CHAR(3) NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO #Order
(OrderNum, 
 Model
)
VALUES
('20200101xx', 
 'AAA'
),
('20200101xy', 
 'AAA'
),
('20200101yy', 
 'BBB'
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #OrderDetail;
GO
CREATE TABLE #OrderDetail
(OrderNum CHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
 Size     VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
 Quantity INT NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO #OrderDetail
(OrderNum, 
 Size, 
 Quantity
)
VALUES
('20200101xx', 
 '6.5', 
 100
),
('20200101xy', 
 '7', 
 100
),
('20200101xx', 
 '7.5', 
 200
),
('20200101xy', 
 '8', 
 100
),
('20200101xx', 
 '8.5', 
 100
),
('20200101xy', 
 '9', 
 200
);

SELECT o.OrderNum, 
       SUM(IIF(od.Size = '6.5', od.Quantity, NULL)) '6.5', 
       SUM(IIF(od.Size = '7', od.Quantity, NULL)) '7', 
       SUM(IIF(od.Size = '7.5', od.Quantity, NULL)) '7.5', 
       SUM(IIF(od.Size = '8', od.Quantity, NULL)) '8', 
       SUM(IIF(od.Size = '8.5', od.Quantity, NULL)) '8.5', 
       SUM(IIF(od.Size = '9', od.Quantity, NULL)) '9', 
       SUM(IIF(od.Size = '9.5', od.Quantity, NULL)) '9.5'
FROM #Order o
     JOIN #OrderDetail od ON o.OrderNum = od.OrderNum
WHERE o.Model = 'AAA'
GROUP BY o.OrderNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the query dynamic, edit the pivot statement to directly insert the Size columns

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 
   OD1.Order_Num,
   OD1.Quantity, 
   mqty.Size    
FROM MoldQty AS mqty
INNER JOIN OrderDetail AS OD1 
   ON OD1.Size = mqty.Size 
)[result1]

PIVOT 
(
MAX(Quantity)
   FOR Size IN([6.5],[7],[7.5],[8],[8.5],[9],[9.5])     -->HERE
)[P1];
```

```
+----+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    | Order_Num  | 6.5  |  7   | 7.5  |  8   | 8.5  |  9   | 9.5  |
+----+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1  | 20200101xx | 100  | NULL | 100  | NULL | 200  | NULL | NULL |
+----+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 2  | 20200101xy | NULL | 100  | NULL | 100  | NULL | 200  | NULL |
+----+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

---

```
/*
CREATE TABLE MoldQTY(Model nvarchar(50), Size nVarchar(15),MoldQuantity int)  
INSERT INTO MoldQTY(Model, Size ,MoldQuantity)  
VALUES
('AAA','6.5' ,1),    
('AAA','7'   ,2),  
('AAA','7.5' ,1),  
('AAA','8'   ,2),  
('AAA','8.5' ,1),  
('AAA','9'   ,2),  
('AAA','9.5' ,1)

CREATE TABLE [ORDER1](Order_Num nVarChar(50), Model nVarChar(12))
INSERT INTO [ORDER1](Order_Num, Model)
VALUES
('20200101xx' ,'AAA'),  
('20200101xy' ,'AAA'),  
('20200101yy' ,'BBB')              
           
CREATE TABLE ORDERDETAIL(Order_Num  nVarChar(50) , Size nVarchar(15),Quantity INT)      
INSERT INTO ORDERDETAIL(Order_Num, Size, Quantity)
VALUES
('20200101xx'  , '6.5'  ,100),    
('20200101xx'  , '7.5'  ,100),    
('20200101xx'  , '8.5'  ,200),    
('20200101xy'  , '7'    ,100),    
('20200101xy'  , '8'    ,100),    
('20200101xy'  , '9'    ,200)

--SELECT * FROM MoldQty
--SELECT * FROM ORDER1
--SELECT * FROM ORDERDETAIL
*/
```